# The key fob will unlock, but not lock the car doors

Tags: peugeot, keyless-entry, peugeot-206

I have a Peugeot 206 manual model 2004. I have a problem with my remote key. I can open my car, but can't lock the door once I press the unlock. I heard a sound click for unlock and directly return, open all the doors. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: There can be many things, from one semi faulty actuator to a simple low battery on the remote causing this error of function. Unfortunately you’ll have to resolve this by trial and error until you get to the root cause. As far as I know it’s not the Keyless locking Module (it does have a fuse).

Answer (score 1):

Double check to ensure all of the doors are closed, as well as the trunk (boot) and hood (bonnet) of the vehicle. Just one of these things being ajar or if the sensors for these are broken (won't register), the doors won't lock. Since they unlock, it shows the system itself is working (car is acknowledging the fob request).

Comment: Also I would just do a high-level check to see if the lock-activation circuit doesn't have a bad connection or failed relay somewhere. If the 'click' isn't heard when you push the lock button then the relay itself isn't getting power (or is just broken).